# After calling the notify method the thread is still waiting

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I have several classes:

- WorkerQueue - queue.
- WorkerRunnable - runnable which contain worker thread method with loop and its stop flag.
- SomeClass - just class for initalize and management thread stuff.

I need to stop thread in destroy method. For it I create endTask method but it doesn't work thread still waiting.
If I replace called endTask method to mWorkerQueue.add(...), it's working fine and thread stop waiting.

```java
class WorkerQueue {
    private Queue<BasePrintTask> mTaskQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private Object obj = new Object();

    public BasePrintTask get() {
        while (mTaskQueue.isEmpty())
        {
            try {
                synchronized (obj) {
                    obj.wait();
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return mTaskQueue.remove();
    }

    public void add(BasePrintTask task) {
        mTaskQueue.add(task);
        synchronized (obj) {
            obj.notify();
        }
    }

    public void endTask() {
        synchronized (obj) {

            obj.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private boolean mFlag = false;
    private WorkerQueue mWorkerQueue = null;

    public WorkerRunnable(WorkerQueue workerQueue)
    {
        this.mPrinterManager = printerManager;
        this.mWorkerQueue = workerQueue;
    }

    public void endThread() { mFlag = false; }

    public void startThread() { mFlag = true; }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(mFlag)
        {
            try
            {
                BasePrintTask task = mWorkerQueue.get();
                
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException el)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class SomeClass
{

    private final Context mContext;
    private WorkerQueue mWorkerQueue = new WorkerQueue();
    private Thread mWorkerThread = null;
    private WorkerRunnable mWorkerRunnable = null;

    public SomeClass(final Context context)
    {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void init()
    {
        mWorkerRunnable = new WorkerRunnable(mWorkerQueue);
    }

    public int prepare() {
        mWorkerRunnable.startThread();
        mWorkerThread = new Thread(mWorkerRunnable);
        mWorkerThread.start();

        return 0;
    }

    public int destroy() {
        mWorkerRunnable.endThread();
        mWorkerQueue.endTask();
        try {
            if(mWorkerThread.isAlive()) {
                mWorkerThread.join();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your WorkerQueue is not thread safe at all. You're doing all operations on it without any synchronisation.

Comment: @MirekPluta, yes I expressed myself incorrectly

Comment: Notify doesn't affect anything but the currently waiting threads. If one thread notifies before another thread waits, the waiting thread misses that notification. If you read the guarded blocks section of the oracle tutorial it advises you to use a variable to avoid this timing issue. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: @NathanHughes, I observed in debug mode: the thread was on hold. After the execution of the line "mWorkerQueue.endTask ();" it was still on hold, but if I replaced the previous line to "mWorkerQueue.add (...)" it exited waiting

Comment: My suggestion is you should read the whole linked tutorial and follow its advice.

Comment: @NathanHughes, yes, condition variable helped me, thanks